# Matching Dates in R

Tags: r, date, merge

I have a data frame concerning the purchases of a shop owner. They don't happen on a daily basis. 
It has two columns: the first one describes the **date**, the second one the **quantity** bought in that date.

I would like to transform it into **daily data**, completing the original dataset, so I created a sequence:

```
a <- seq(as.Date("2013/11/19"), as.Date("2017/04/22"), "days")
```

The first date corresponds to the one of the first purchase, and the second one of the last one, of the original dataset.

The classes are both "*Date*".

How can I **merge** the two dataset *by "date"*, even if, obviously, they have different rows length? I would like to have a dataframe with  **daily** "**Date**" as **first** **column**, and "**Quantity**" on the **second** **one**, with **zeros** where purchases didn't happen.

Comment: This would be a left join operation :) you can use dplyr package for that

Answer (score 3):

Using base R:

```
# create sample data frame with sales data
test <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2017/08/12", "2017/08/15", "2017/09/02")), quantity = c(3,2,1))
# create the date range
dates <- data.frame(date = seq(min(test$date), max(test$date), by = "day"))
# perform the left join
# (keeping all rows from "dates", and joining the sales dataset to them)
result <- merge(dates, test, by.y = "date", by.x = "date", all.x = TRUE)
```

In the merge function, by.y and by.x are the columns used to join the dataset, while `all.x` tells you, that all rows from `x` (in this case `dates`) should be kept in the resulting data frame.

Comment: And then after can convert NA to 0 with: result[is.na(result)] <- 0